# Upload File to database using kendoUI

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, kendo-ui, upload

Hy Friends. I want to make upload File to database postgre using KendoUI. I was searching in google but there is no appropriate answer. would you mind to help me please especially the method to save the file to database. thankyou

Comment: Have you made any attempts to do this yourself? If so, it would be good to see your code.

Comment: I followed this http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/upload/async. But I confused how to save that file to database. oh ya I using angularJS Yeoman as client side and Lumen Framework as server.